# How do I find out if python script was invoked by piping sth into it or called directly?

Tags: python, pipe

My python program both accepts its main input from a command line parameter (`sys.argv[1]`) and through piping (`sys.stdin`).

But it needs additional parameters which will shift their position in the `sys.argv` list when the main input is not present.

How do I find out if the script was invoked directly

```
myscript.py "input" "add_param"
```

or by piping

```
echo "input" | myscript.py "add_param"
```

Just checking the number of params is not enough. There are more (optional) parameters and
I also want to give the right error message for missing parameters.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this in general. Command line tools typically include a parameter (sometimes just a - at the end) to indicate that additional info is on stdin.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sys.stdin.isatty()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#file.isatty).

If the script is executed using pipe (`|`), it return False.

```
>>> sys.stdin.isatty()
True
```

Comment: Thanks. I've read this before, but wasn't sure if piping really is the same as a 'non interactive shell'.

Comment: Also applies when input redirection is used (e.g. `myscript.py < infile.txt`)

Comment: But it doesn't work if the script is called from another non-interactive script or remotely through a tunnel like ssh, e.g. `ssh user@host "myscript.py input add_param"`. "interactive" and "command line" are not quite the same thing.